# Alternative for q.all in angualarJs or node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, q

Is there any alternative for `q.all` because the callback for

`q.all().then()`  will be called only when all http calls succeeds.

Even if one http call fails , it will enters into `.catch` part.

Is there any way so that it enters into `q.all().then()`  part even if few http calls fail?

Comment: You could use a `forEach` loop, and then for every succesfull you have a `.then()` clause, and for every failing call you have a seperate `catch` block. I can't test it, but something like `q.forEach(x => x.then().catch());`

Answer (score 1):

If you're actually talking about the `Q` library, then [`Q.allSettled()`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseallsettled) is precisely for this purpose:

```
Q.allSettled([promise1, promise2]).then(function (results) {
    // results is an array of objects of the form:
    //  { state: "fulfilled", value: ... }
    // or
    //  { state: "rejected", reason: ... }
});
```

If you're talking about the `$q` included in AngularJS, it doesn't have this method, but you could make your own ad-hoc version:

```
myApp.service('allSettled', ['$q', function ($q) {
    return function (values) {
        return $q.all(values.map(function (value) {
            return $q.resolve(value)
                .then(function (result) {
                     return { state: "fulfilled", value: result };
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                     return { state: "rejected", reason: error };
                });
        }));
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either handle catch error after each request return sth else, says null.

Or you can use bluebird `Promise.some()` and define your threshold of `n` requests ok out of total.

```
Promise.some([
    ping("ns1.example.com"),
    ping("ns2.example.com"),
    ping("ns3.example.com"),
    ping("ns4.example.com")
], 2).spread(function(first, second) {
    console.log(first, second);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Q.allSettled()` or `Q.any()`. See the docs:

- https://github.com/kriskowal/q#combination

Even more options with Bluebird. See:

- http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.some.html
- http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.any.html
- http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.race.html

Note that there is no `Promise.any` and `Promise.some` in the native promises (yet) and There is no `Q.some`.